# How to delete object in array using localstorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have to delete object in array and it should be deleted from localstorage. I am trying to delete it by using splice method but not actually getting how to use it. 
Folloeing is my code which i have tried-

```
 var details = [];



 function addEntry() {


   var existingEntries = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allEntries"));
   if (existingEntries == null) existingEntries = [];


   var srno = document.getElementById("txtpid").value;
   var name = document.getElementById("txtpname").value;
   var dob = document.getElementById("txtpdob").value;
   var email = document.getElementById("txtpemail").value;
   var address = document.getElementById("txtpaddr").value;
   var contact = document.getElementById("txtpmobile").value;

   var obbbj = {
     txtpid: srno,
     txtpname: name,
     txtpdob: dob,
     txtpemail: email,
     txtpaddr: address,
     txtpmobile: contact
   };
   localStorage.setItem("details", JSON.stringify(obbbj));

   existingEntries.push(obbbj);
   localStorage.setItem("allEntries", JSON.stringify(existingEntries));
   showEntry();
   console.log(existingEntries);
   //location.reload();
 }


 function showEntry() {
   var messageBox = document.getElementById("display");
   messageBox.value = "";
   document.getElementById("txtpid").value = "";
   document.getElementById("txtpname").value = "";
   document.getElementById("txtpdob").value = "";
   document.getElementById("txtpemail").value = "";
   document.getElementById("txtpaddr").value = "";
   document.getElementById("txtpmobile").value = "";


   var render = "<table border='1'>";
   render += "<tr><th>Srno</th><th>Name</th><th>Birthdate</th><th>Email</th><th>Address</th><th>Contact</th></tr>";


   var allEntriesoo = {};
   var detailsOOO = {};
   for (i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
     var key = localStorage.key(i);
     var person = localStorage.getItem(key);
     if (key == 'allEntries')
       allEntriesoo = JSON.parse(person);
     if (key == 'details')
       detailsOOO = JSON.parse(person);
     var data = JSON.parse(person);

   }

   for (var key in allEntriesoo) {
     console.error(allEntriesoo[key])
     render += "<tr><td>" + allEntriesoo[key].txtpid + "</td><td>" + allEntriesoo[key].txtpname + " </td>";
     render += "<td>" + allEntriesoo[key].txtpdob + "</td>";
     render += "<td>" + allEntriesoo[key].txtpemail + "</td>";
     render += "<td>" + allEntriesoo[key].txtpaddr + "</td>";
     render += "<td>" + allEntriesoo[key].txtpmobile + "</td>";
     render += "<td><input type='button' value='Delete' onClick='return deleteEntry(" + i + ")'></td>";
     render += "<td><input type='button' value='Edit' onClick='return editInfo(" + i + ")'></td></tr>";

   }
   render += "</table>";
   display.innerHTML = render;
 }

 function nameVal() {
   document.getElementById("txtpname").focus();
   var n = document.getElementById("txtpname").value;
   var r;
   var letters = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
   if (n == null || n == "") {
     alert("please enter user name");
     return null;
     n.focus();
   } else {
     if (n.match(letters) && n != "") {
       r = ValidateEmail();
       return r;
     } else {
       alert("please enter alphabates");
       document.getElementById("txtpname").value = "";
       document.getElementById("txtpname").focus();
       return null;
     }
   }
 }

 function ValidateEmail() {
   var uemail = document.getElementById("txtpemail").value;
   var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
   if (uemail.match(mailformat)) {
     return true;
   } else {
     alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");
     document.getElementById("txtpemail").value = "";
     document.getElementById("txtpemail").focus();
     return null;
   }
 }

 function alphanumeric() {
   var uadd = document.getElementById("txtpaddr").value;
   var letters = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;
   if (uadd == null || uadd == "") {
     alert("plz enter address");

     uadd.focus();
   } else {
     if (uadd.match(letters)) {
       return true;
     } else {
       alert('User address must have alphanumeric characters only');
       document.getElementById("txtpaddr").value = "";
       document.getElementById("txtpaddr").focus();
       return false;
     }
   }
 }

 function cntVal() {
   var n = document.getElementById("txtpmobile").value;
   var r1;
   var letters = /^\d{10}$/;
   if (n !== null || n !== "") {
     if (n.match(letters)) {
       r1 = alphanumeric();
       return r1;
     } else {
       alert("please enter contact number");
       document.getElementById("txtpmobile").value = "";
       document.getElementById("txtpmobile").focus();
       return null;
     }
   } else {
     alert("please enter contact Number");
     return null;
     n.focus();
   }

 }

 function deleteEntry(id) {
   console.log("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaAAAA");

   var entry = localStorage.getItem('allEntries') JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('allEntries')): [];
   var index;
   for (var i = 0; i < entry.length; i++) {
     if (entry[i].id === id) {
       index = i;
       break;
     }
   }
   if (index === undefined) return
   entry.splice(index, 1);
   localStorage.setItem('entry', JSON.stringify(entry));
 }

 function clearstorage() {
   localStorage.clear();
   window.location.reload();
 }

 window.onload = function() {
   showEntry();
 };
```

Comment: You're more likely to get helpful answers if you format your code more neatly, so it's more readable and remove the unnecessary extra bits, like commented-out code. If you can reduce it to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you might even find that you spot the answer yourself.

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error? What is the issue exactly? As far as the `splice()` method goes, you seem to be using it correctly.

Comment: the issue is entry is not removing from local storage. please can you help me to figure it out?

Comment: Help format the code

Answer (score 0):

In your deleteEntry function you are setting a new item in localStorage called 'entry'. So you are not setting 'allEntries' and thats probably why its showing up like that, 'allEntries' has not been updated. So just set all entries again. localStorage.setItem('allEntries', JSON.stringify(entry));

You are also missing the '?' for you variable 'entry'...

var entry = localStorage.getItem('allEntries') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('allEntries')) : []; <-- it should look like this.

Its the same as an 'if else statement'

```js
function deleteEntry(id){
    console.log("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaAAAA");

      var entry = localStorage.getItem('allEntries') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('allEntries')) : [];
        var index;
        for (var i = 0; i < entry.length; i++) {
            if (entry[i].id === id) {
              index=i;
              break;
            }
        }
        if(index === undefined) return 
        entry.splice(index, 1);
        localStorage.setItem('allEntries', JSON.stringify(entry)); <--- like this

    }
```

Comment: I added an edit to my answer. You are missing the '?' in your variable declaration for entry

Comment: Yes i have added the '?' but still it is not removing object from localstorage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use create a temporary object and then replace it in localStorage.

```
 function deleteEntry(id){
    console.log("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaAAAA");

      var entry = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('allEntries'));
        var temp= [];
        for (var i = 0; i < entry.length; i++) {
            if (entry[i].id !== id) {
              temp.push(entry[i]);
            }
        }
        localStorage.setItem('entry', JSON.stringify(temp));
    }
```